# I recently changed my compiler path to run c++ code, but now I can't run any python code. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, g++

How can I set my path so that I can easily switch between several coding languages? I am new to stuff like this so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you even need to keep changing the path value, to switch between languages? Why can't contain the path for python, as well as, C++?

Comment: How did you change the compiler path?

Comment: What's a "compiler path"? Do you mean the `PATH` environment variable? That can contain multiple paths, so the paths to your C++ compiler and your Python interpreter should be able to coexist without any problems.

Comment: Yes the PATH environment variable is what I meant sorry.

Comment: Your C++ compiler and your Python implementation can also be in the same directory; they are completely unrelated.

Comment: What's your os?

Comment: @WebScrapingPancake Once again, why do you need to keep changing said variable? Why can't it contain both paths, in your case?

Comment: I don't need to change the PATH variable, but I did not know this. First time running something other than python.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set anything. They should coexist without issue. Have you tried this? What errors are you getting? What OS? What compilers/interpreters?

Comment: The problem was that I deleted python from my Path variable like a fool and running repair python fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to set anything. Whatever reads your python code is a completely separate entity from what compiles/understands your C++ code. Your operating system's PATH variable contains a list of places for the system to look for programs.

Your python and C++ tools can co-exist in your PATH without butting heads or causing any issues. I have C++, python, and C# stuff all installed and they get along fine.